# How to fix a div size when it is styled "inline"

Tags: html, css

When a div is styled as "inline", it seems all its dimension variables lost effect.

for example

```
<div id="test" style=" border: 1px solid;padding:3px;width:40px; height:100px;">
foobar
</div>
```

gives me a big box, but after I add inline style, the box shrink to the smallest size.

for example

```
<div id="test" style="display:inline; border: 1px solid;padding:3px;width:40px; height:100px;">
foobar
</div>
```

My question is, is there a way that I can keep the div inline (same line as some preceded text) and at the same time able to fix its size. (either div or span)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The width of inline elements is ignored.  From my experience, in cases like this using a `float` will solve the issue.

You can also use `inline-block`, but if you have to support older browsers you may not wish to use this.

The floated div will float to the left of the the nearest block element parent (assuming this parent is also not floated). If you need more control of where the div is floating, add a wrapping (non-floated and block) div around your floated div

Comment: Thanks and it works well. As a side question, by any chance, do you know how to make the "float:left" float to only a certain div? instead of the very left of the whole webpage? thanks

Comment: The floated div will float to the left of the the nearest block element parent (assuming this parent is also *not* floated).  If you need more control of where the div is floating, add a wrapping (non-floated and block) div around your floated div.

Comment: Or add an #element:after { clear: left; } - this is the way the whole world is heading for with .clearfix-classes (e.g. bootstrap).

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block` or (better) `display: block; float: left`

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;`

PS: `inline-block` is not available in some older browsers.